# ActiveMQ Artemis: Postgres DB persistence: Auto commit

Tags: postgresql, activemq-artemis

In my project I am using postgres DB for message storage.

ActiveMQ Artemis is used as a embedded server inside a Spring-based Java web application.

The actual datasource is being set programatically before starting the JMS server

```
                DatabaseStorageConfiguration storeConfiguration = (DatabaseStorageConfiguration)this.activeMQServer.getConfiguration().getStoreConfiguration();
                if (null != storeConfiguration) {
                    storeConfiguration.setDataSource(this.getDataSource());
                }
```

I noticed that while using postgres DB for message storing Artemis is setting the autoCommit state as false. This is done for all the DB connections returned from the datasource irrespective of any explicit send/receive call to JMS server.
If file based storage is used then this automCommit state of the connection is true.

Questions:

1. What is the reason of setting the autocommit value to false and that too for all the connections?
2. What will be the impact if this value is set as true explicitly while creating connection pool using tomcat.

Please note there is no transaction manager defined on this datasource.

Comment: Are you _sharing_ a datasource between the broker and your own application?

Comment: @JustinBertram Yes and that is causing the side effects. Bascically transactions are committing randomly and causing deadlocks.

Comment: When the broker gets a connection from the datasource it sets autoCommit as necessary for the work it is doing. Your application should do the same rather than simply assuming the value of autoCommit is set appropriately for its needs. Generally speaking, I would recommend _against_ sharing a JDBC datasource between your application and the broker.

Comment: Agree. I am using separate dataspurce for Artemis now. Thanks @JustinBertram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of the issue is to use dedicated datasource for Artemis.

Answer (score 1):

1. Setting the autocommit to false allows for manual management of the transaction in the journal implementation. I think the journal implementor will need some fine grained way to handle failures and rollbacks.
2. In theory none, as the implementor should set it to false. In practice ...